# What is the purpose of marking the positive terminal of an 50% duty cycle oscillating source?

Tags: components, diagram

Some circuit diagrams I look at contain a sinusoidal voltage source with a `+' hovering to the side of the wire a little ahead of that component.

`____(~)_+___`

If the source has a duty cycle of 50% with no DC component, why bother marking it's 'positive' end?

Comment: Yo don't say but is this a schematic for SPICE simulation?  Or is it showing say Mains power?  Context please.

Comment: Well, it could be to specify phase.  Two identical sources in series will either add to 2x the amplitude or cancel each other out depending on whether either of them is turned upside down.  So the '+' is useful in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where you see it:

1. It could be a reference for circuit analysis:  the signal generator would have an associated function related to t = 0. Let's say we use a 1 volt peak (2vpp) cosine.  Without knowing which side of the source is +/-, for t = 0 you wouldn't know if you were at +1 volt or -1 volt, and your circuit diagram would be incompletely defined.  In some software programs (e.g. Microcap) they define the AC source signal with a +, exactly for this reason.
2. If you are using real equipment in the real world, it could designate e.g. which cable was the black one and which was the red one.
3. If the function generated isn't completely AC, then it matters: lots of function generators have DC offset capability.

In the end, it's application specific and it depends on whether the circuit is academic or real hardware.  For some applications, it just doesn't matter and people won't fault you.

Answer (score -1):

It is just common practice. In reality there is no need, but people like reference points, and things that feel familiar to them. People who have a lot of experience with electronics know that there is almost always a positive and a negative end (even if it is arbitrary and does not matter). Putting a + is just a way to make people feel comfortable.